# $P_3(x)$ and $R_3(x)$ of $f(x)=e^{-3x}+3 \sin (x)-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

the maclarin series for $\sin(x)$

is $$ \sin(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k*x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

so summation to $k=3$

$$ 
 \begin{aligned}
 \sum^{k=3}_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k*x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
 &= \frac{(-1)^0*x^{2*0+1}}{(2*0+1)!}
  + \frac{(-1)^1*x^{2*1+1}}{(2*1+1)!}
   +\frac{(-1)^2*x^{2*2+1}}{(2*2+1)!}
   + \frac{(-1)^3*x^{2*3+1}}{(2*3+1)!}
  \\&=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}
 \end{aligned}
$$

the maclarin series for $e^{-3x}$ using $e^x=\sum \frac{x^k}{k!}$

$$\begin{aligned}
  e^{-3x} &= \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(-3*x)^k}{k!}= \frac{(-3*x)^0}{0!}+\frac{(-3*x)^1}{1!}+\frac{(-3*x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(-3*x)^3}{3!}
  \\ &=1-3x+\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}-\frac{3^3*x^3}{3!}
 \end{aligned}
$$

So, the third degree polynomial of the function is nothing more than

$$
 \begin{aligned}
 P_3(x)&=\sum^3_0 \frac{(-3x)^k}{k!} +3*\sum^3_0 \frac{(-1)^k*x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}-1
       \\ &=1-3x+\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}-\frac{3^3*x^3}{3!}+ 3(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!})-1
       \\ &=1-3x+\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}-\frac{3^3*x^3}{3!}+ (3x-3\frac{x^3}{3!}+3\frac{x^5}{5!}-3\frac{x^7}{7!})-1
       \\& =-3x+\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}-\frac{3^3*x^3}{3!}+ (3x-3\frac{x^3}{3!}+3\frac{x^5}{5!}-3\frac{x^7}{7!})
       \\& =\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}-\frac{3^3*x^3}{3!}+ (-3\frac{x^3}{3!}+3\frac{x^5}{5!}-3\frac{x^7}{7!})
       \\&=\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}
                +(-\frac{3^3*x^3}{3!}+ -3\frac{x^3}{3!})+ 3\frac{x^5}{5!}-3\frac{x^7}{7!}
       \\&=\frac{3^2x^2}{2!}+
       (-3-3^3)\frac{x^3}{3!}+ 3\frac{x^5}{5!}-3\frac{x^7}{7!}
       \\&=\frac{9*x^2}{4}+
       (-30)\frac{x^3}{3*2}+ 3\frac{x^5}{5*4*3*2*1}-3\frac{x^7}{7*6*5**4*3*2*1}
       \\&=\frac{9*x^2}{4}+
       (-5)\frac{x^3}{1}+ \frac{x^5}{5*4*2*1}-\frac{x^7}{7*6*5**4*2*1}
         \\&=\frac{9x^2}{4}
         -5x^3+ \frac{x^5}{40}-\frac{x^7}{1680}
 \end{aligned}
  $$

finding the primes  of $f$

$$\begin{aligned}
 f^0(x)&=e^{-3x}+3\sin(x)-1
 \\f^1(x)&= -3*e^{-3x}+3\cos(x)
 \\ f^2(x)&=(-3)^2*e^{-3x}-3*\sin(x)
 \\ f^3(x)&=(-3)^3*e^{-3x}+3\cos(x)
 \\ f^4(x)&=(-3)^4e^{-3x}+3\sin(x)
 \end{aligned} $$

The remainder of the $P_n(x)$ is  $$R_n(x)=f^{n+1}(c)/(n+1)! (x-a)^{n+1} \text{ for some } x\in[a,x]$$

In our case $n=3$ and $c\in[0,x]$

$$R_3(x)=\frac{f^4(c)}{4!}(x)^{4} =\left ((-3)^4e^{-3c}+3\sin(c) \right)*\frac{x^4}{4!}  $$

---

***Anything wrong?????*** ***If no I want to delete it Or even better vote to close it if  its ok***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you made a few mistakes in your calculations (in particular $2!=2$ and not $4$).
$$e^{-3x}=1-3 x+\frac{9 x^2}{2}-\frac{9 x^3}{2}+\frac{27 x^4}{8}-\frac{81 x^5}{40}+\frac{81
   x^6}{80}-\frac{243 x^7}{560}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ These make
$$e^{-3x}+3\sin(x)-1=\frac{9 }{2}x^2-5 x^3+\frac{27 }{8}x^4-2 x^5+\frac{81 }{80}x^6-\frac{73
   }{168}x^7+O\left(x^8\right)$$